# How to search field that starts with?

Tags: jhipster

Jhipster entity with filtering produce api with for example:
    http://localhost:8080/api/general-addresses?postalCode.contains=41

```
which execute sql: ............. postalCode LIKE '%41%'
http://localhost:8080/api/general-addresses?postalCode.contains=
which execute sql: ............. postalCode LIKE '%%'

Is it possible to make request with sql: LIKE '41%'  ?
```

Comment: You must code it manually by modifying JHipster generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding this value as new criteria and write custom specification. For example add criteria:

```
private String postalCodeLike;
```

Please note that I'm using String not StringFilter.

And add custom specification:

```
if (criteria.getPostalCodeLike() != null) {
      specification = specification.and((root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) ->
                    criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.upper(root.join(FirstRelationedEntity_.fieldName, JoinType.INNER).join(SecondRelationedEntity_.fieldName, JoinType.INNER)
                 .get(Product_.postalCode)),  criteria.getPostalCodeLike().toUpperCase() + "%"));
}
```